# How to use OAuth 2.0 for security purpose when its deprecated in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have a Spring Boot application. Spring Boot 3 and Java 17. I want to use OAuth 2.0 for security purpose. I checked a few articles. It states that OAuth 2.0 is deprecated. Can anyone suggest how to use OAuth2?

There are options like Keycloack but eventually APIs will go to GCP.

Comment: You are reading the wrong articles. The separate project is deprecated and is now has been part of Spring Security itself.

Answer (score 0):

The separate [Spring Security OAuth](https://github.com/spring-attic/spring-security-oauth) project has been replaced with OAuth2 support in the Spring Security project. Spring has published a [migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Migration-Guide) and deprecated all the classes in the former project.

Comment: Okay thank you for the response ,But now I am confused between Keycloak and Spring security 6 authorization server.